# How to inject environment variables in Vercel Non-Next.js apps?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I deployed a regular React app to Vercel and would like to have a `API_BASE_URL` environment setting with different values for `development`, `preview` and `production` environments.

Typically, I'd use `dotenv` npm package with my webpack config setting up the variables for `local` or `production` depending on the build by looking into `env.local` and `env.production` respectively.

The `env.production` would look like this:

```
API_BASE_URL=#{API_BASE_URL}
```

Then, I'd have my deployment pipeline replace all instances of `#{___}` with the respective values available in the pipeline.

However, the regular way in Vercel seems to be to make a Next.js app and the environment variables in the project will be automatically available in the `process.env` variable in the backend code.

Is there anyway for us to have environment variables in a non-Next.js in Vercel?

I'm thinking I have 2 ways forward:

1. There is actually an easy way
2. Create my own build and deployment pipeline to replace the `#{___}` placeholders and deploy using `vercel deploy` command.

Comment: curious... why not go the route of using https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd & then specifying .env files for each of your environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, I was overlooking an important fact. Vercel deploys builds and deploys changes in the same step.

2 commits in `preview` branch which are merge them both to `main` in 1 single commit: that's a totally new thing (a new build is created for every single commit in every environment).

This goes against the [build once, deploy to multiple environments principle](https://12factor.net/build-release-run) but I suppose Vercel's team considered that in their quest to make the development process as simple as possible.

Anyway, I worked out 2 solutions:

1. In the build command, insert the environment variables e.g. in the package.json:

```
scripts: {
  "build": "webpack --env production --env VERCEL_ENV=$VERCEL_ENV"
}
```

2. Create my own build and deployment pipeline and then deploy to vercel using `vercel deploy` command. It also works but I think I'm going to stick to the option for simplicity, at least in the meantime.

Comment: In the script is the $VERCEL_ENV a variable and is how can you prefix a variable in the package.json

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar issue on my SPA (React + Webpack) app on deployed on Vercel. This is what worked for me.

https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack#properties

**webpack.config.js**

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {

  // OTHER CONFIGS

  plugins: [
    new Dotenv({
      systemvars: true
    })
  ]
};
```

Doing it like this I was able to read env vars from:

- Vercel build runtime (ex: VERCEL_ENV)
- .env file in my src folder
- Env variables defined in Vercel console